# jQuery .change() on select list broken in chrome latest version

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, select

I am using Version 27.0.1453.110 m of chrome on windows 8 pro. I have a simple SELECT element and a .change() function on it. This function should get called when the selected item changes. Works great on IE and FireFox and also in older versions of chrome but in the latest version of chrome its broken. I get the change() triggered when I click on up/down arrow or page up/page down scrollbar directly **without clicking on an option first**. However once I click on an option this behaviour vanishes and it works fine. Any ideas how to fix this issue? Am I doing something wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/TH8wk/16/

```
 <form method="POST" action="">
<select id="a100" size="3">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="4">4</option>
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="211">211</option>
    <option value="2344">2344</option>
    <option value="2qwr">2qwr</option>
</select>
    </form>


    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#a100').change(function () {
            alert('change');
        });
    });
```

Comment: Id's shouldn't start with numbers, and your code works for me

Comment: The fiddle you posted seems to work fine in Chrome for me (same version)

Comment: Are you sure it works in js fiddle? Make sure you refresh it and do not click on an option. Directly click on up/down arrow and it fires up the alert message for me. Also my client complained about this behaviour and hence the question. I am using windows 8 pro

Comment: What do you get if you write `alert($(this).val());` instead of `alert('change');` when the issue occurs ?

Comment: vcarel, It shows 4. see the updated fiddle...

Answer (score 0):

Now I see what you saying. Chrome is doing the same to me as well. It isn't pretty, but if you save the old value, a simple if statement solves the problem. See http://jsfiddle.net/jG275/2/

```
    var oldVal;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        oldVal = $('#a100').val();
        $('#a100').change(function () {  
            if ($(this).val() != oldVal) {
                alert('change() called...new value: ' + $(this).val());
                oldVal = $(this).val();
            }
        });
    });
```

However, it doesn't seem that this should be necessary. But at least it fixes the issue.

Comment: Yes this works and I have already applied something similar to that to fix the issue temporarily. But this looks like a major bug with Chrome.

Comment: @Raj - I certainly agree. If the value doesn't change, Chrome shouldn't be raising the `change()` event.